# Copying keys from one Map to another

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two maps. One with default values of `0` and one with set values.

*For example:*

```
Map<String,Integer> defaultTaskScores = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
   put("Phalanxing", 0);
   put("Shieldwalling",0);
   put("Tercioing",0);
   put("Wedging",0);
}};

Map<String,Integer> taskScores = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
   put("Phalanxing", 90);
   put("Shieldwalling",56);
   put("Wedging",24);
}};
```

I want to put into `taskScores` a pair of key-value from `defaultTaskScores` which key's isn't in `taskScores`. For this example it's putting Tercioing with value of `0`.

`taskScores` maps are in the list

```
List<CourseResult> courseResultList;

public class CourseResult {
  private final Person person;
  private final Map<String, Integer> taskResults;

  public CourseResult(final Person person, final Map<String, Integer> taskResults) {
      this.person = person;
      this.taskResults = taskResults;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over `defaultTaskScores` and use [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) to add the missing keys to `taskScores`:

```java
defaultTaskScores.keySet().forEach(k -> taskScores.putIfAbsent(k, 0));
```

**EDIT:**
An alternate approach could be to apply the default value when retrieving a score from the map. Instead of calling `taskScaores.get(someKey)`, you could use `taskScores.getOrDefault(someKey, 0)`.

Comment: I would probably use `defaultTaskScores.forEach(taskScores::putIfAbsent)` just in case the default map is changed so that a key is not mapped to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create iterate over the entries of `defaultTaskScores` with enhanced `for`-loop using entry set as a source, or by invoking [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) method on the`defaultTaskScores` map directly.

To update `taskScores` you can use Java 8 methods:

- [`putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)):

```
defaultTaskScores.forEach(taskScores::putIfAbsent);
```

- or [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)):

```
defaultTaskScores.forEach((k, v) -> taskScores.computeIfAbsent(k, (key) -> v));
```

<sup>*In case if you're not comfortable with lambda expressions and method references, have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) created by Oracle.*</sup>

***Sidenote:*** avoid using obsolete double brace initialization, it creates an anonymous class under the hood and might cause memory leaks. Since Java 9 we have a family of overloaded factory methods `Map.of()` and method `Map.ofEntries()` which produce an *immutable map*. When you need a map which is *mutable* like in this case, you can wrap it with a `HashMap`, like that:

```
Map<String, Integer> taskScores = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    "Phalanxing", 90, "Shieldwalling",56,"Wedging",24
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Only put in the Map those values if the key is not already there:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : defaultTaskScores.entrySet()) {
  taskScores.putIfAbsent( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
}
```